# PHP not working under IIS on WIndows 7

Tags: php, iis, iis-7

I recently installed PHP on IIS/Windows 7, but it isn't working. I am getting the entire source file in the browser window.

FastCGI Settings shows c:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php-cgi.exe
Handler Mappings has

- Request Path: *.php
- Modue: FastCgiModule
- Executable: C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php-cgi.exe
- Request Restrictions: File or Folder, All verbs, Script Access

Comment: Should be moved to http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Is PHP installed correctly, does `echo phpinfo();` work?

Comment: If I start the PHP console app and type `echo phpinfo();`, nothing happens. In fact, no matter what I type nothing happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer the answer you gave one hour ago, which said *(quoting)* :

> In some PHP hosts you can being a
>   script block with `<?`. In IIS the
>   block must start with `<?php`.

That's not a setting of IIS ; **that's a configuration option of PHP**, which is called **[`short_open_tag`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)** : if that configuration option is enabled, short tags *(i.e. `<?`)* will be accepted.

Using short open tags is often not considered as a good pratice, as they can be disabled -- and they are, by default, with recent versions of PHP -- but, if you are admin of your server, you should be able to re-enable them.

And, for information, they are also considered as "*bad*" because they can cause problem with XML files, which start with `<?xml` -- if `short_open_tag` is enabled, this will cause troubles, as it starts with `<?`

Enabling `short_open_tag` is just a matter of editing your `php.ini` file, and using

```
short_open_tag = On
```

Instead of

```
short_open_tag = Off
```

No need to edit/path all your PHP files ;-)

*(Well, if you are admin of your server, that is...)*

Comment: Thanks for the explaination and the warning.

Comment: using <?php worked for me, but changing the php.ini did not have the affect described, using PHP 5.3 on IIS 7, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In some PHP hosts you can being a script block with `<?`. In IIS the block must start with `<?php`.

Needless to say, I'm going to be spending the resst of the day fixing all the script files I inherited.